# Kubernetes operators

Tags: kubernetes

https://www.openshift.com/learn/topics/operators
An Operator is a method of packaging, deploying and managing a Kubernetes-native application.

I'd like to understand if the application binary itself is packaged into the operator or is the application binary available somewhere else (for eg: an image registry) and the operator knows how to fetch the application binary ?

I'd appreciate your help with this .

Answer (score 1):

The binary is NOT packaged into the operator, and typically the operator does not fetch the binary either.  You install the 'operand' and then you install the operator.  This may be facilitated by Helm - either one chart or two.

The operator needs to find what it's operating on. It may be as simple as 'all XYZ applications in the same k8s namespace', or maybe it's specified via labels, annotations, etc.